# Sub-widgets won't render (will have 0 height) in Dojo

Tags: widget, dojo

Have a look at this simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mercmobily/y4uG2/10/

Basically I declare a Widget, and start adding away sub-widgets. At one point, I have the sub-widget "section" which is a templated widget with a tab container and sub-tabs.

The main widget has:

```
'<div data-dojo-type="Section" data-dojo-props="title: \'Sub Widget\'" data-dojo-attach-point="section"></div>' +
```

And that "section" widget has:

```
  templateString: '' +
    '  <div>' +

    '    <div class="subWidget" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" tabPosition: \'left-h\'" dojo-attach-point="tabCont" >' +

      '      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: \'Second Widget one\'">Second Widget One</div>' +
      '      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: \'Second Widget Two\'">Section Widget Two</div>' +

      '    </div>'+
    '    </div>'
```

Now, I am having a bit of a hard time getting the sub-widget, "section", to render properly.
On my actual program right now I played with:

1. doTemplate
2. height attribute in CSS
3. Catching resize() from the main widget and calling resize() in the sub-widget

(About point (3), I had to do something like:

resize: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        console.log("Resize in main widget called!");
        this.settingsTab.resize();
  }

At this point, I am going insane and hence the question: what is the *accepted*, *normal* and *common* way to make sure that, in the fiddle, the sub-widget is rendered when you instantiate the main one?

PLUS, do I need to specify the height:100% for every tab container I ever use? (it looks like it)

Thank you!

## UPDATE

I updated the fiddle. At this point I added a "height" to the tab container. After that, rsizing the browser window actually does the trick (!). I am not quite clear why I need that height there, but OK.

http://jsfiddle.net/mercmobily/y4uG2/16/

I also did a on() when a user clicks on the "broken" widget, and -- guess what -- resize is run and it renders fine.

This makes even less sense. Why is my own widget behaving any different than the ones defined within the template? I started all sorts of theories: height cannot be calculated because it isn't displayed, for example. But then the SAME should apply to the *other* tab with sub-tabs, labelled as "Complex" on the left hand side!

I am out of ideas. No, really.

Comment: Hi Merc I am kind of facing similar issue,but my main widget is not a TabContanier, but the sub widget which is a tab container is not rendering properly in my main widget. When main page loads no tabs get displayed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is a typo, as Frode mentioned, but you will still need to click one of the tabs if you want your tab content to appear in the `SubWidget`.

I suggest that you correct the typo and make your widget subclass `ContentPane` rather than `_WidgetBase` to solve this issue, as `ContentPane`s know how to resize themselves, like this :

```
declare('SubWidget', [ContentPane, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

      templateString: ''...
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/YwWst/

By the way, there is no need to specify `widgetsInTemplate : true` in 1.8. Adding `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` is enough...

Comment: Hi Philippe. I accepted your answer, as it leads me towards the right direction. Now... would you be able to tell me why http://jsfiddle.net/mercmobily/y4uG2/23/ If you resize the window, the tab SubWidget *grows* in size; AND if you turn it into a ContentPane, the writing "After the tabs" outside of the screen space?

Comment: Well, you have to take into account the size of the text that you wrote before your tabs. If you set the height to 100%, it will have the same height as the parent box, so basically you should put your TabContainer inside that ContentPane ALONE (no text before or after). If you want to have text before or after, put it in other content panes, or give your tab container a height < 100%.

Comment: OK but did you notice that at each resize the content pane actually _grows_? Is that a dojo bug I just hit with my luck?

Comment: There is no problem if you extend ContentPane rather than _WidgetBase... why did you go back to that one ?

Comment: Actually the external ContentPane is useless. You can achieve what you want with your current code, but with only the tabContainer as a direct child of your SubWidget's domNode. See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/y4uG2/26/

Comment: Philippe: I guess this is a different question now. I realise that inheriting from ContentPane works, and that the extra ContentPane is useless. Now I am just _dead_ curios as why it's doing what it's doing -- making the container bigger and bigger at each refresh!

Answer (score 0):

The templateString in your SubWidget has a typo. Could it simply be that?

```
...<div style="height:100%" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" tabPosition: \'left-h\'" data-dojo-attach-point="tabContainer" >'...
```

Should probably be:

```
<div style="height:100%" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="tabPosition: \'left-h\'" data-dojo-attach-point="tabContainer" >'
```

That seems to do the trick in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y4uG2/18/