# Dojo and heights of widgets

Tags: layout, widget, dojo

I am trying to figure out how "heights" are worked out when instancing a widget. 
I am not going very far...

At the moment, I have a simple HTML page that goes like this:

```
</head>
<body class="claro"><div id="appContainer"></div></body>
</html>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#appContainer {
    height: 100%;
}
```

When my app starts, this happens (this is a simplification):

```
 // Create the "application" object, and places them in the right spot. 
 appContainer = new BorderContainer( {} , 'appContainer');
```

Left as it is, the app has the right size and everything.

** Q1: why do I need to specify the height for html, body and #appContainer?

Then, I have:

```
 // Create the new BookingDojo application
 bookingDojo = new BookingDojo( { id: 'bookingDojo', region: 'center'  } );
 appContainer.addChild( bookingDojo );
```

and finally:

```
 appContainer.startup();
```

BookingDojo has this CSS:

```
#bookingDojo {
   height: 100%;
}

.bookingDojo {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And uses this template:

```
templateString: '' + 
    '<div>' + 
    '  <div class="bookingDojo" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: \'headline\'">' + 

    '    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: \'center\', tabPosition: \'left-h\'">' + 
    '      <div data-dojo-type="hotplate.bd.Settings" data-dojo-props="title: \'Settings\'">Settings</div>' + 
    '      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="title: \'attempt\', tabPosition: \'top\'" data-dojo-attach-point="settingsTab">' + 
    '        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:\'One\'">ONE</div>' + 
    '        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:\'Two\'">TWO</div>' + 
    '      </div>' + 
    '      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: \'Two\'">Section Two</div>' + 
    '      <div data-dojo-type="hotplate.bd.Dashboard" data-dojo-props="title: \'Dashboard\'">Section One</div>' + 
    '    </div>'+ 
    '  </div>' + 
    '</div>',
```

Note that
     class="bookingDojo"
 within the widget:

** Q2: If I take out wither #bookingDojo or .bookingDojo from the CSS, the app isn't rendered properly.

I mean, I also have a problem where I cannot get the Dashboard to render properly, because it comes out with height 0, but that's a different (probably related) story for which I have added a different post.

** Q3: Can somebody *please* explain to me the whole "heights of widgets" issue? I am aware that widgets need startup(), and I am aware that if you create an inner-widget and it's invisible, it will need a resize(). But that's obviously not all I need to know, since I find myself struggling over and over to get a widget to appear (and I go trying CSS, doLayout, resize, etc.) so... well, I must be missing something!

Thanks a million,

Merc.

Comment: Not an answer, but in my experience, some widgets need an explicitly set height (e.g. tab container), some need a parent with explicitly set height (e.g. scrollpane iirc) and some don't need it at all (e.g. a button dijit).
Some widgets will also act strangely if you append them to a DOM node that's detahced from the document (or if it's hidden, as you mention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, the documentation says :

> The outer size must be specified on the BorderContainer node.  Width must be specified for the sides and height for the top and bottom, respectively.  No dimensions should be specified on the center; it will fill the remaining space.

In your CSS, you are setting the appContainer to take the full screen, because a height of 100% means 100% of the parent element... and your structure is

```
<html><body><div id="appContainer">...etc
```

Therefore, you have to set both body and html to 100% if you want your appContainer to take 100% of the screen height...
By default, block elements are already 100% wide, so no need to set the width there...

For Q2, I suggest you have a look at your html in firebug. You will notice a div with id="bookingDojo", which will be the outmost div of your template. The first inner div has a class="bookingDojo". Again, these 2 divs are nested, and for that reason, they both need to be set to a height of 100% if you want them to fill-in the full height of their parent container div (which is your BorderContainer, which you already set to be 100% high). I made a little example here http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/7JQWC/
You will see something like your bookingDojo where I set #bookingDojo to 100% height, but didn't specify a height for the .bookingDojo class. Try to set it and you will see the red border expand...

For Q3, well, I think the whole issue here is understanding how nested boxes get their sizes, so for that you can refer to Q1 and Q2...

I hope this helps...

Comment: 1) Does this apply to every single container in Dojo? That is, every time I create a tabContainer, I also need to set its height in the CSS? 2) If I have a simply div around things, I don't need to set the height right? That is, this "rule" only applies to container divs?

Comment: I am testing this... it applies to _every_ div! If I add a level of <div> around the template, suddenly the red box is not extending... I think I am getting somewhere...

Comment: I will build you a statue if you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642369/sub-widgets-wont-render-will-have-0-height-in-dojo It comes with a fiddle and everything...

Comment: (Maybe wait 22 hours, will put a bounty on it!)